# Reduce size of serverless deploy package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a python script that I want to run as a lambda function on AWS. Unfortunately, the package is unzipped bigger than the allowed 250 MB, mainly due to numpy (85mb) and pandas (105mb)

I have already done the following but the size is still too big:

1) Excluded not used folders:

```
package:
    exclude:
        - testdata/**
        - out/**
        - etc/**
```

2) Zipped the python packages:

```
custom:
    pythonRequirements:
        dockerizePip: true 
        zip: true
```

If I unzip the zip file generated by `serverless package` I find a `.requriements.zip` which contains my python packages and then there is also my virtual environment in the `.virtualenv/` folder which contains, again, all the python packages. I have tried to exclude the `.virtualenv/../lib/python3.6/site-packages/**` folder in `serverless.yml`, but then I get an Internal server error when calling the function.

**Are there any other parameters to decrease the package size?**

Answer (score 2):

The `.virtualenv/` directory should not be included in the zip file.
If the directory is located in the same directory as `serverless.yml` then it should be added to exlude in the `serverless.yml` file, else it gets packaged along with other files:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - ...
    - .virtualenv/**
  include:
    - ...
```

Answer (score -6):

(Are you sure you need `pandas` and `numpy` in a microservice? There is nothing "micro" in those libraries).

There is a way. Deploy you Lambda with Zappa https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa. It's a convenient way to write, deploy and manage your Python Lambdas anyway. But with Zappa you can specify an option called `slim_handler`. If set to `true`, most of your code will reside at S3 and will be pulled once a Lambda is executed:

> AWS currently limits Lambda zip sizes to 50 megabytes. If your project
>   is larger than that, set slim_handler: true in your
>   zappa_settings.json. In this case, your fat application package will
>   be replaced with a small handler-only package. The handler file then
>   pulls the rest of the large project down from S3 at run time! The
>   initial load of the large project may add to startup overhead, but the
>   difference should be minimal on a warm lambda function. Note that this
>   will also eat into the memory space of your application function.

Comment: I think this info is outdated, the size of the zip file doesn't matter, what matters is the unzipped file size, which must be less than 250 Mb.

Comment: This information is current. Deployment package cannot be more than 50 Mb. The size of uncompressed code can't be more than 250 Mb, but that is not relevant here. Zappa will download code/libraries to `/tmp` which allows up to 512 Mb of storage.

Comment: hmm...thats weird, I deployed several times a 50+ Mb zip but it only stopped working when the unzipped size was larger than 250Mb and it explicitly said that the _unzipped_ file size must be <250Mb in the error message.

Comment: I can't comment on that, but the docs are very clear, only 50 Mb for the deployment package: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: It seems like as long as you load the zip via s3 it can be over 50MB. The 250MB unzipped limit is the same either way.